# Fooling Ruby's case operator, ===, with proxy objects

Tags: ruby, proxy, operators, case, introspection

I'm trying to make a proxy object that transfers almost all method calls to a child object, essentially the delegator pattern.  For the most part, I'm just using a BasicObject and passing every call with method_missing to the child object.  So far, so good.

The trick is that try as I might, I can't fool Ruby's case operator, so I can't do:

```
x = Proxy.new(15)
Fixnum === x #=> false, no matter what I do
```

This of course makes any `case x` operations fail, which means the proxies can't be handed off safely to other libraries.

I can't for the life of me figure out what === is using.  The proxy works fine for all of the class-based introspection I know of, which is all correctly passed to the child object:

```
x.is_a?(Fixnum) #=> true
x.instance_of?(Fixnum) #=> true
x.kind_of?(Fixnum) #=> true
x.class #=> Fixnum
```

Is `Module#===` just doing some kind of magic that can't be avoided?

Comment: A word of warning: if you can achieve your goal without masquerading your proxy as a `Fixnum` by delegating `is_a?`, `instance_of?`, `kind_of?`, `class` etc., please do so! Changing these methods may lead you (or someone using/maintaining your code) straight to debugging hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it is. `Module#===` is implemented in C, examining the object's class hierarchy directly. It doesn't look like there's a way to fool it.

Comment: Thanks.  What ennui this brings.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I think what you're looking for is the [`Delegator`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/index.html) class.</strike>

Your Proxy class should subclass the Delegator class, then define `__getobj__` and `__setobj__` to get and set the target object.

Forget that, I tried it myself and it doesn't work.

EDIT:

As grddev mentions, the technical issue is that Fixnum is being sent the :=== method. Thinking about it further, however, I think Ruby's current behavior is correct. Since a Delegator is supposed to be an abstract interface to hide implementation details, instances of Proxy are correctly not identified as a kind_of? Fixnum.

If you really want the Proxy class to be a kind of Fixnum but wish to decorate it with methods, the logical thing to do is to either subclass Fixnum, or create a ProxyMethods module and extend individual instances of Fixnum.

Of course, since you can't really do Fixnum.new, you'll have to subclass Fixnum in order to extend a single instance, but the general rule stands.

Comment: The technical behavior is correct only if you assume that there is a form of object introspection unavailable to the programmer, which, it seems, there is--in C.  Unfortunately this proxy needs to track any kind of object, not just Fixnums, so extending really doesn't help (and for various reasons, extending Object is also not useful).

Comment: Well, I see your point. You would hope that :=== is implemented to `send :instance_of?, MyClass` to your proxy object, but that is in fact not the case. I still maintain though that if you are trying to masquerade as an object, but want some kind of meta-functionality, creating a Tracking class that decorates and tracks individual objects is a better design. Non-singleton objects can be extended, and singleton instances (Fixnum and Symbol for instance) can be wrapped and extended, or specically handled.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it does `Fixnum === x`, which means that the method `===` is called on `Fixnum` and not on `x`. You could replace all `===` methods in existence, (and also watch for when new `===` methods are introduced), but that would be a lot of work, and quite fragile.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably do a search for the BlankSlate
class. This class strips out most of the methods from a normal Object and the website has an example of a simple Proxy class that will print out all methods being called. This shoul give you a better picture of what is happening. Sorry I can't give you a fuller answer but I'm on my phone. Hope that helps.